# R rvest: extracting html table that are loaded dynamically

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am trying to extract an html table and convert it to a data.frame or data.table in R.

I would like to extract the table containing Bitcoin's historical data:
https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/ethereum/historical-data/?start=20170101&end=20201113

(full Xpath: `/html/body/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div/ul[2]/li[5]/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/table`)
[image]

This is what I have tried so far:

```r
library(magrittr)
library(rvest)
URL <- "https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/historical-data/?start=20170101&end=20201113"
PRICES <- read_html(URL) %>% html_nodes("table")
```

As you can see however, the historical prices table does not show up in the output:
[image]

My guess is that the table is loaded *after* the rest of the page is loaded.

Ideally I would like the extraction method to work with other cryptocurrencies historical tables, e.g.:
https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/ethereum/historical-data/?start=20170101&end=20201113

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by @AllanCameron we can extract the table using `Rselenium` and `rvest`. Here's a script that worked for me:

```r
library(RSelenium)
library(rvest)
library(magrittr)

URL <- "https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/ethereum/historical-data/?start=20170101&end=20201113"

# Open firefox and extract source
rD <- rsDriver(browser = "firefox", verbose = FALSE)
remDr <- rD[["client"]]
remDr$navigate(URL)
html <- remDr$getPageSource()[[1]]

# Extract table from source
DF <- read_html(html) %>% 
  html_nodes("table") %>% 
  `[[`(3) %>% 
  html_table %>% data.frame

# Close connection
remDr$close()
```

Answer (score 2):

You're right - this table is loaded dynamically by an XHR call after the page is loaded, so you can't get it with `rvest`. Perhaps the best solution is to find the address to the API that produces the table. You can do this with developer tools in your browser. You then need to parse the json, which can be tricky. For example, in your case we could do something like:

```r
url <- paste0("https://web-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/",
              "price-performance-stats/latest?id=1027&include_volume=true&", 
              "time_period=all_time,24h,7d,30d,90d,365d,yesterday")

res <- httr::content(httr::GET(url), "parsed")$data$`1027`$periods
df <- do.call(rbind, lapply(res, function(x) unlist(x$quote$USD[1:9])))
df <- as.data.frame(df, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
for(i in c(1, 3, 5, 7, 9)) df[[i]] <- as.numeric(df[[i]])
for(i in c(2, 4, 6, 8)) df[[i]] <- strptime(df[[i]], "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
df[rev(order(df$open_timestamp)),]

#                open      open_timestamp      high      high_timestamp        low
# 24h       458.44767 2020-11-12 15:30:29  470.5202 2020-11-13 15:03:02 452.072417
# yesterday 462.95952 2020-11-12 00:00:00  467.6778 2020-11-12 10:08:13 452.072417
# 7d        440.22446 2020-11-06 15:30:29  473.5789 2020-11-11 18:50:25 428.456353
# 30d       380.66672 2020-10-14 15:30:29  473.5789 2020-11-11 18:50:03 362.597418
# 90d       434.50894 2020-08-15 15:30:29  487.2119 2020-09-01 22:17:01 316.774346
# 365d      185.43604 2019-11-14 15:30:29  487.2119 2020-09-01 00:00:00  95.184301
# all_time    2.83162 2015-08-07 00:00:00 1432.8800 2018-01-13 00:00:00   0.420897
#                 low_timestamp    close     close_timestamp percent_change
# 24h       2020-11-12 18:27:13 467.0052 2020-11-13 15:30:29      1.8666241
# yesterday 2020-11-12 18:27:13 461.0053 2020-11-12 23:59:59     -0.4221218
# 7d        2020-11-07 20:11:13 467.0052 2020-11-13 15:30:29      6.0834207
# 30d       2020-10-16 09:21:41 467.0052 2020-11-13 15:30:29     22.6808486
# 90d       2020-09-05 18:55:23 467.0052 2020-11-13 15:30:29      7.4788382
# 365d      2020-03-13 00:00:00 467.0052 2020-11-13 15:30:29    151.8416350
# all_time  2015-10-21 00:00:00 467.0052 2020-11-13 15:30:29  16392.5082715
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Isn't there any alternative to add some kind of delay for the `rvest` call so the table is loaded before it extracts the information? My whole script is based on that table so it would be much easier if I can extract that table in particular.

Comment: @mat all rvest does is request the page and parse what is returned as html. The difference between rvest and your browser is that your browser has a built-in JavaScript engine that can run JavaScript code. Part of this JavaScript code is to send another request to the server (an Ajax call) that returns the json. The JavaScript engine then parses the json to build the table. This is all a very active and complex process that takes your browser some time which is why you need to wait for the table in your browser. You can wait all you like, rvest won't build a dynamic webpage for you to scrape.

Comment: @mat if you need to scrape dynamic webpages, your two options are to generate the request for the json and parse it yourself (as I have shown in my answer) or to use R to control a web browser via RSelenium. Both are quite tricky to master if you don't know much about JavaScript or html - though I see from your profile you know some JavaScript

Comment: Thanks for all the info. I had a quick look at the api, and the historical data is not available with a free plan ([see](https://coinmarketcap.com/api/documentation/v1/#operation/getV1CryptocurrencyOhlcvHistorical)). I'll have a try with `Rselenium`.